# Spark executors can not connect to mysterious port 35529

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I have a spark cluster (7*2 cores) which is set up on spark 2.0.2, next to an hdfs cluster.

When I use Jupyter to read some hdfs file, I see the app firing up, using 14 cores and 3 , but all  the worker fail to launch any task because of a network impossibility to connect to a strange "localhost" port 35529.

```
spark       = SparkSession.builder.master(master).appName(appName).config("spark.executor.instances", 3).getOrCreate()
sc          = spark.sparkContext
hdfs_master = "hdfs://xx.xx.xx.xx:8020"
hdfs_path   = "/logs/cycliste_debug/2017/2017_02/2017_02_20/23h/*"
infos       = sc.textFile(hdfs_master+hdfs_path)
```

I see : 
[image]

(that make me think that it is strange to see 14 cores allocated when only 3*2 are possible : ie spark.executor.instances * nb of cpu by node) :

Here is the cluster summary :

**Executor Summary for app-20170227140938-0009 :**

```
ExecutorID  Worker  Cores   Memory  State ▾ Logs
1488    worker-20170227125912-xx.xx.xx.xx-38028 2   1024    RUNNING stdout stderr
1489    worker-20170227125954-xx.xx.xx.xx-48962 2   1024    RUNNING stdout stderr
5       worker-20170227125959-xx.xx.xx.xx-48149 2   1024    RUNNING stdout stderr
1486    worker-20170227130012-xx.xx.xx.xx-47639 2   1024    RUNNING stdout stderr
1490    worker-20170227130027-xx.xx.xx.xx-44921 2   1024    RUNNING stdout stderr
1485    worker-20170227130152-xx.xx.xx.xx-50620 2   1024    RUNNING stdout stderr
1487    worker-20170227130248-xx.xx.xx.xx-42100 2   1024    RUNNING stdout stderr
```

and an example of error for one worker :

**stderr log page for app-20170227140938-0009/1488:**

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/02/27 14:37:57 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 5864@vpsxxx.ovh.net
17/02/27 14:37:57 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
17/02/27 14:37:57 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
17/02/27 14:37:57 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
17/02/27 14:37:58 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/02/27 14:37:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark
17/02/27 14:37:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark
17/02/27 14:37:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/02/27 14:37:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/02/27 14:37:58 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/02/27 14:38:01 WARN ThreadLocalRandom: Failed to generate a seed from SecureRandom within 3 seconds. Not enough entrophy?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1713)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:35529
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:35529
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

I understand there is a simple communication issue between two processes.

So I display the /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
193.xx.xx.xxx   vpsxxxx.ovh.net vpsxxxx
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if SPARK_LOCAL_IP is set to the correct IP in each slave.